# How display Windows security dialog

Tags: delphi, windows-7-x64, delphi-2007

I have an application that sometimes access fileshare in local network.
In this case the path is stored in fEBookPath.
If user entered login and password since before all is good. But if not FindFirst don't return 0. In that case I want to display the same security dialog that Windows Explorer show.
Like this

[image]

My simplified code

```
if FindFirst(fEBookPath + '*.*', faDirectory, vSearchRecFolder) = 0 then
begin
  // Existing code to access fEBookPath 
end
else
  // Display Windows security dialog to enter login + password
```

Comment: [WNetAddConnection2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385413(v=vs.85).aspx) + CONNECT_PROMPT which will prompt and setup the connection.

Comment: You are connecting to a network resource, not displaying dialog. The result type is `DWORD`, you probably don't want to connect to a printer but disk. And those empty strings you can simply `nil`.

Comment: Ok thanks for advices

Comment: If you want to post the solution, do so properly by doing it as an answer below, not by editing it into the question itself. This is covered in [Can I answer my own questions here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 3):

This code should do what I want

```
function TLogonForm.ShowSecurity: DWORD;
var
  UNCPath,UserName,PassWord: string;
   NwR : TNetResource;
begin
  UNCPath := '\\xenapp06';
  NwR.lpLocalName:= '';
  NwR.lpProvider := '';
  NwR.dwType      :=  RESOURCETYPE_DISK;
  NwR.lpRemoteName:= PChar(UNCPath);
  Result := WNetAddConnection2(NwR,  nil, nil, CONNECT_INTERACTIVE or CONNECT_PROMPT);
end;
```